# How to have maven run just JMeter tests (no other life cycles)

Tags: maven, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-maven-plugin

We're using the `maven-jmeter-plugin` and I've setup a jmeter profile. When I run `mvn -Pjmeter verify` the various maven life cycles get run, but none of them need to.

How can I  run just the JMeter tests?

```
<profile>
  <id>jmeter</id>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${jmeter.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>jmeter-tests</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>jmeter</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <testResultsTimestamp>false</testResultsTimestamp>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</profile>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it looks like the author of the plugin did not implement a MOJO that would support direct invocation, hence the plugin must be used as a part of lifecycle execution — within the `<build>` section.

If you need to run tests quickly, you could try to **temporarily** change the `<phase>` to some earlier one, for example `validate`. I'm sure, though, this is not the phase the plugin intended to be run in, so you can't change this permanently.

Comment: Do you know enough about implementing a MOJO that would support direct invocation to clue me in on how I could patch it to do so?  Or maybe a link to an example or tutorial specific to MOJO direct invocation?

Comment: Annotate the MOJO class with `@Mojo(name="goalName",requiresDirectInvocation=true)`. A starting place for MOJO development is http://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html

Comment: Thanks for the details, I've made the modification and submitted a pull request.

Comment: But the pull request is being backed out.  See https://github.com/Ronnie76er/jmeter-maven-plugin/pull/70 for details

Answer (score 2):

You can run just JMeter tests with the following command:

```
mvn jmeter:jmeter -Pjmeter
```

To see the rest of the goals you can execute the following:

```
mvn help:describe -DgroupId=com.lazerycode.jmeter  -DartifactId=jmeter-maven-plugin -Ddetail=true
```